# Among, in, of, out of for choices

Tags: prepositions

Do all of these make sense?

- He was the only chosen person **out of** a hundred others.
- He was the only chosen person **of** a hundred others.
- He was the only chosen person **among** a hundred others.
- He was the only chosen person **in** a hundred others.

It's just that I've seen all four **in**, **among**, **out of** and **of** used with choosing and selecting:

- Two shots **in** ten tries hit the target.
- The house was **among** the trees.
- Only three **of** five songs were recorded today.
- They were **out of** a bigger group of animals.

Are they all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your sentences

> He was the only chosen person **out of** a hundred others.

Your self-made sentences are not really analogous to your examples.

More similar examples might be

> He was the only one *out* **of** a hundred others chosen.
>   He was the only chosen person *from* **among** a hundred others.
>   He was the only chosen person, *one* in a hundred.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose something **from** a pool of options. Out of your self-written sentences, only the first one,

> He was the only chosen person out of a hundred others,

is correct as it makes use of "out of", which is analogous to "from".

Even in the example sentences, you gave, only the last one,

> They were out of a bigger group of animals,

which uses "out of", conveys the sense of a particular thing being chosen from a pool of options.